# How can I count _ in csv file with command line?

Tags: terminal, count

I have csv document with "_" in some lines. And I want to find out how many _ there are via terminal.

My file look like this:

```
  NP_000008.1 MAAALARASGPARRALC
NP000010.7 MAPWPHENSSLAPWPDLPTL
NP_000011.2 MTLGSPRKGLLMLLMALVTQG
NP_000016.1 MAPWPHENSSLAPWPDLPTL
NP000043.4 MDPSMGVNS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -c '_' file.csv
```

try the above